# Adding a post notice to a late answer doesn't count in review

Tags: support, review, moderator-tools, late-answers, post-notices

When a moderator is in `review => Late Answers` I've found if I add a post notice to a one line sentence seeking for a better answer it will not count but the system moves to the next late answer.  When a moderator adds a post notice shouldn't that count in Late Answers as it is offered on the answer?